# python .sort() has higher priority for __lt__ than __gt__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, oop

I have seen similar questions, but they did not answer why python `__lt__` has higher priority than `__gt__`?

Quick example, let me give a superclass and a subclass:

```
class Person(object):
    id = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = Person.id
        Person.id += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id

class SubPerson(Person):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.name > other.name
```

Here in superclass `Person`, I created a `__lt__` method, to compare based on Person's `self.id`. In sub class `SubPerson`, I created a `__gt__` method to compare based on the `self.name`.

What I found is that if I created a number of `SubPerson` instances in a list:

```
s1 = SubPerson('WWW'); s1.id = 14
s2 = SubPerson('XXX'); s2.id = 12
s3 = SubPerson('YYY'); s3.id = 11
s4 = SubPerson('ZZZ'); s4.id = 13
lst2 = [s2, s1, s4, s3]
lst2.sort()
print([i.__str__() for i in lst2])  # >>> ['YYY', 'XXX', 'ZZZ', 'WWW']
```

What I found is that:
if `__lt__` is defined in superclass, then even if you define `__gt__` in subclass, it will still sort by the `__lt__` method in superclass

But if it is the other way around, define `__gt__` in superclass and `__lt__` in subclass, then it will then sort by `__lt__` in subclass

If the two method names are the same (both `lt` or both `gt`), obviously, the subclass will override superclass, as it should be.

But it seems when they are different, it follows a different rule: by whatever `__lt__` defines. I've also noticed that even if in one class, if both `__lt__` and `__gt__` are defined (based on different things, it will still sort by `__lt__` method)

SO back to my question, is my observation true or not? and since I am a beginner, and I have not read through the whole python documents, can somebody point me out where in the documents that this rule is written.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort): “This method sorts the list in place, **using only < comparisons between items**.”

Comment: @Ryan but it seems that it will still sort if I only define `__gt__` method??

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: You defined both; the subclass still inherited `__lt__` from the parent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I mean, I can go back and delete the `__lt__` in the parent, and sub will then sort by `__gt__`.

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: See user2357112's answer; there is a reflective test applied (checking the right hand side's reversed comparison, `__gt__`) when the left hand side doesn't support the direct (`__lt__`) comparison. You benefit by accident. In practice, you should really only define `__eq__` and `__lt__`, then [decorate the class with `functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to define the other comparisons in terms of them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  OK, that actually answers the question, that the fact `__gt__` can still work alone got me confused, it is a side effect. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`list.sort` uses only `<` comparisons. [This is documented.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)

Binary operators like `<` will try the left-hand operand's method first unless the right-hand operand's class is a subclass of the left-hand operand's class. The other operand's method will only be considered if the first method is missing or returns `NotImplemented`. The left-hand operand's method for `<` is `__lt__`, and the right-hand operand's method is `__gt__`. [This is also documented.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__)

Since all your list elements have the same class and `__lt__` always succeeds, only the `__lt__` methods end up getting called.

Comment: But I noticed that if I only define `__gt__` method, it will still sort? So in a way, `__lt__` is not the must have????

Comment: I don't have to define `__lt__` to make `.sort()` work, I can delete all the `__lt__` and leave only `__gt__` it will still sort

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 I think your question about why __gt__ works is answered in the answer itself - it took me a sec to understood too: "The other operand's method will only be considered if the first method is missing or returns NotImplemented." So if __lt__ does not exist, then it reverses the operands and your __gt__ on the righthand operatnd is considered.